# Android new location API Altitude is always zero

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am using Google new location Api in my app like this

```
private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create().setInterval(2000).setFastestInterval(1000)
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        if(location.hasAltitude()){
            Log.e(TAG, "Altitude " + location.getAltitude());
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "Location does not have altitude");
        }
    }
};
```

but `location.hasAltitude()` always false, I have tested it on real device and in open area, but it does not have altitude anywhere, but if I am using the old location Listener, its working fine,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 3.1.36 version of the API fused location provider always returns false there (at least for me when having GPS turned on), so you may want to stick with `LocationManager` and GPS provider.

Hopefully they will improve the fused algorithm in the future release.