# Android Google Map API V2, Altitude always 0

Tags: android, google-maps

I just use the code from the google maps sample,  "MyLocationDemoActivity.java", and paste them into my app.

The API release is May, 2013, the device is Samsung S3.

The location comes from **LocationClient getLastLocation()**, but the Altitude is always 0. (latitude, longtitude and accuracy is OK)

The same thing, same place I got from Google map API V1 has the altitude. But switch to V2, every location data comes from **LocationClient getLastLocation()** has no altitude. It's ALWAYS 0.

Actually, no matter the release **MAY 2013** or **Feb 2013**, the altitude always return 0.

On release Feb 2013, I use  **GoogleMap getMyLocation()** to get current location. All the data are correct except the ALTITUDE. It's ALWAYS 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894247/android-new-location-api-altitude-is-always-zero/16904006#16904006

Comment: Thanks...And according to Google, there isn't an official issue tracker for the issue. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=56803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks...And according to Google, there isn't an official issue tracker for the issue. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=56803